# Loaded not child component firs before child component loading. Page blinking (lazyLoading+Angular Universal)

Tags: javascript, angular, frontend, lazy-loading, angular-universal

I have Routes with components and child components in lazyloading. When I try to load child component "Schedule", before it loaded not child component "Profile" without lazyLoading. 
How to load a child component "Schedule" faster or not show component "Profile" until the child component "Schedule" loads?

Comment: I don't know if it suits for your case but, you can use RouterEvents (https://angular.io/api/router/RouterEvent) to show loader while the module is loading, also for a more concrete answer can you provide a code?